# Remove Search Icon from Taskbar in Windows 1909

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons

I would like to remove the completely useless search icon from my Windows 10 taskbar.

[image]

Usually, there used to be a way to do this, by right-clicking on the taskbar and then selecting Search -> Hide search icon.

However, after resetting my Windows PC yesterday, this option seems to be gone.

[image]

Any ideas how to removed this useless icon from my taskbar?
I'm running Windows 10, 1909, OS Build 18363.752

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to remove the Search Bar from Windows is to make a registry key change. Since you will be changing the registry make sure you make a backup before you make any changes. Here is an [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows) on how to backup and restoring the registry if you do not know how to do it.

1. Launch Registry Editor (regedit.exe) as the current user NOT as admin (this is so you can edit the Current User hive)
2. Navigate to the following key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search`
3. Change the **SearchboxTaskbarMode** hexadecimal value to **0**
   [image]
4. Click OK to save the changes
5. Restart your computer to apply the changes

Comment: Unless you have an unusual account setup, `HKCU` is the same whether elevated or not.